# Crontab command not execute php artisan command

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I need to set php artisan scheduler command in crontab file for automatic execution on every minute. But It do not execute the php artisan command

I have tries to set

- - - - - cd /path-to-project; && php artisan schedule:run

This do not execute the command

---

I have also tried execute simple php file code by

- - - - - cd /path-to-project; && php write_sample.php

This executes the file code.

---

> crontab -e

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-project; && php artisan schedule:run
```

I need to execute artisan schedule commands for cron jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first go to php installation directory then you are able to run php artisan command.

Following is an example which shows how to use it:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /var/www/public_html/yoursite artisan Demo:Cron
```

Comment: I can run php command, but can not run php artisan command from crontab.
Manually php artisan command can run, only from crontab file php artisan command is not executing.

Comment: It is because php is not recognised at crontab. I have mentioned how to use php in crontab.

Comment: Yes, It's working by set full php path like "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php [command]". Thanks @Dhananjay.